# Переделать php post-запрос в ajax get-запрос

Tags: php, ajax

Есть класс, в котором есть функция `checkDomain()`, к которой я обращаюсь после события `isset($_POST['submitBtn'])`, так вот мне нужно сделать этот вызов через ajax, как мне это сделать? Пытаюсь так, но не пойму что прописать в параметре `url` так как этот php-скрипт находится в том же файле. Подскажите что не так в моем коде.
ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var num = <?php echo (isset($_POST['domainname'])) ? $_POST['domainname'] : ''; ?>; //чтобы знать с какой записи вытаскивать данные
        $(function () {
            $("#btn-search").click(function () { // Выполняем если по кнопке кликнули

                $.ajax({
                    url: "", // Обработчик
                    type: "GET",       // Отправляем методом GET
                    data: {"num": num},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response == 0) {// Смотрим ответ от сервера и выполняем соответствующее действие
                            swal ('Ошибка!');
                        } else {
                            var html = '';
                            $.each(response, function (i, el) {
                                html += '<div>'+el.domain+'</div>'+'<div>'+el.availstr+'</div>';
                                $('#srch-result').append(html);


                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    });
```

Обработка POST запроса на php выполняю так:

```
<?php    

if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
{
    $domainbase = (isset($_POST['domainname'])) ? $_POST['domainname'] : '';
    if (strlen($domainbase)>0)
    { 

    foreach ($newdomain as $value)
        {
        // если была отмечена галочка, то проверяем домен
        if (isset($_POST[$value->name])) $value->checkDomain($domainbase);                      
        }

}
 }
```

Далее собственно сам класс-обработчика:

```
class domain_to_check
{
var $name;
var $whois_server;
var $whois_server_answer;
var $break_checkbox;
var $show;
// конструктор  
function domain_to_check($name_c,$whois_server_c,$whois_server_answer_c,$break_c,$show_c)
    {
    $this->name = $name_c;
    $this->whois_server = $whois_server_c;
    $this->whois_server_answer = $whois_server_answer_c;
    $this->break_checkbox = $break_c;
    $this->show = $show_c;
    }
//показываем чекбокс    
function showcheckbox()
    {
    if ($this->show == true) 
        { 
             echo "<div class='col-sm-4'><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"".$this->name."\"><span style='color: #fff;'>.".$this->name."</span> </div>";

        }   
    }
  //проверяем домен
  function checkDomain($domain)
        {
            // Состоит ли строка только из латинских букв, цифр и "-", длиной от 2 до 30 символов
        $domain = strip_tags($domain);
    if (ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}$",$domain)) 
        {
        $domain = $domain.".".$this->name;

            $availstr = "<a href=\"https://www.reg.ru/\" target=\"_blank\"><b>Можно зарегистрировать</b></a>";
            $con = fsockopen($this->whois_server, 43);
            if (!$con) return false;
            fputs($con, $domain."\r\n");
            $response = ' :';
            while(!feof($con)) 
                {
                    $response .= fgets($con,128); 
                }
            fclose($con);

            if (strpos($response, $this->whois_server_answer))
                {   
                    echo "<div class='col-sm-10 alert alert-success'>$domain $availstr</div>";
                    return 1;

                }
                else 
                {
                    echo "<div class='col-sm-10 alert alert-danger'>$domain <b>ЗАНЯТ</b></div>"; 
                    return 0;  
                }
            }
            else{
                 echo "<div class='col-sm-10 alert alert-info'>Домен введен некорректно!</div>";
            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Если адрес тот-же, то в url можно поставить:

```
window.location.href
```

И `$_POST['submitBtn']` у вас не сработает, вы его в data не передаёте.